# GnuCash - Seeing Different Sized Fonts in Same Reports Generated By Different Users

Tags: xorg, debian-buster, gnucash

**GnuCash version 3.4; Debian 10 (Buster); Cairo 1.16.0; Xorg 1.20.4**

At our business, we have two different users (User1 and User2) on the same host that generate GnuCash invoices to bill our customers. However, User1's invoices turn out being scaled about 10% larger than those generated by User2. Both users use the same GnuCash configuration files (found in **/home/user1/.local/share/gnucash** , with a symbolic link to said directory present in the proper place in User2's home directory). When I open identical User1 and User2-generated PDF reports in Firefox, text in 15.2 sized font for the User1 report shows up as 13.6 sized font in the User2 report.

Normally, this would not be much of a problem, but the boss wants all invoices to be formatted identically, to include scaling (she says we are more professional-looking that way).

The reports are all generated via GnuCash thusly: With the desired invoice visible on the screen, we hit the "Print" button, then choose the "Print to File" option (hence the Cairo involvement). All such PDF printing operations are scaled at **100%**.

I experimented with creating a pristine new user on the host and generated a GnuCash report using the above steps. It was scaled exactly like a report generated by User2 (when using the same **stylesheets-2.0** file as User1/User2), so I suspect that there is some configuration set somewhere in User1's account that is causing his reports to come out a little larger than they should.

I've checked everything I can think of, but this one is driving me crazy!

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: Are they all printed to the same 'paper size'? (That is, for example, A4 vs Letter?)

Comment: Yes, both are printed to "US Letter" (8 1/2" x 11")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by different values in xsettings between the two users. Using Xfce Menu -> Settings -> Settings Editor, I was able to match the sizes of the fonts listed against xsettings -> FontName (previous to this, User1 listed a font size of 9 here, User2 a font size of 10).

After a reboot, I was able to verify that both users now produce invoices of identical scaling.

Happy boss, happy life!

P.S. An interesting side effect of this situation (and which ultimately led to me finding the solution) was that fact that the default fonts that GnuCash declared in the style sheets were different between the two users...

P.P.S. BTW, User1 stated that they most likely changed the default font size setting when they were fiddling with Xfce Menu -> Settings -> Appearance. Turns out that changing the value of the "Default Font" setting under the "Fonts" tab of the resulting "Appearance" window will change the value of the subject xsetting...